# PHP typecasting float->int

Tags: php, types, casting

Given this PHP code:

```
// total is 71.24 (float)
$value = $total * 100;
var_dump($value);
$valuecast = (int)$value;
var_dump($valuecast);
settype($value, 'int');
var_dump($value);
```

var_dump($value) gives **float(7124)**

var_dump($valuecast) gives **int(7123)**

var_dump($value) after settype gives **int(7123)**

How can I get the correct type conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For float to int, I'd suggest [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php). This is to cater to IEEE float imprecision.

Answer (score 4):

From PHP Manual on [TypeCasting Float to Integer](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting)

> **Warning**
>
> Never cast an unknown fraction to integer, as this can sometimes lead to unexpected results.
>
> ```
> <?php
>     echo (int) ( (0.1+0.7) * 10 ); // echoes 7!
> ?>
> ```
>
> See also the [warning about float precision](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#warn.float-precision).

Comment: The de3 link doesn't seem to be online anymore. So try

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#warn.float-precision