# Divide integer and get integer value

Tags: php

In languages like C or Python 2, if I divide an integer by an integer, I get an integer:

```
>>> 8/3
2
```

But in PHP, if I divide an integer by another integer with `/`, sometimes I get a float:

```
php > var_dump(6/3);
int(2)
php > var_dump(8/3);
float(2.6666666666667)
```

I'd like to do division like in Python or C, so that 8/3 is 2. How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate [questions/2055469](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055469/php-typecasting-float-int)

Comment: IF you round the above, you will get `6`, what do you need 5 or 6?

Comment: @Starx: there are more than one rounding types: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking. So if you round 5.6 - you don't know what you get (without specifying of how you want it to be rounded)

Comment: @zerkms, Yes indeed function like `ceil()` and `floor()` are the functions that rounds up differently.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

As of PHP 7, we can use the [intdiv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) built-in function to get an integer value:

```
intdiv(8,3); // 2
```

For earlier versions of PHP, we can use the [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function to get an integer rounded value:

```
round(8 / 3); // 3
```

Or we can use the [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) function to get an integer value:

```
floor(8 / 3); // 2
```

Comment: Don't agree. floor(-8 / 3) === -3.0 but should be -2

Comment: Note that `floor()` will return a `float` NOT an integer, so you get `2.0` and not `2`. Cast the result to make sure you get an integer: `(int)floor(8/3)`

Comment: @ByScripts *-8/3 = -3* is just as valid a way for integer division to work as *-8/3 = -2*. The former is "truncation towards negative infinity", and the latter is "truncation towards zero". Both have advantages, and different languages choose different behaviours. For example, C truncates towards zero (as does PHP 7's `intdiv`), while Python truncates towards negative infinity.

Comment: Note that ceil() is always rounding up.

Answer (score 91):

In PHP 7, there is [intdiv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) function doing exactly what you want.

Usage:

```
intdiv(8, 3);
```

Returns `2`.

Comment: That really is a great surprise this function is only introduced with PHP 7 :) Oh well, better late than never.

Comment: is there is any solution like this in php 5.6

Comment: Not as straightforward as this, no. In PHP 5.6, use the accepted answer :)

Comment: This should be favor solution as `floor(-8 / 3)` would return -3 while `divint(-8 / 3)` would return -2

Answer (score 26):

There is no integer division operator in PHP. 1/2 yields the float 0.5. The value can be casted to an integer to round it downwards, or the round() function provides finer control over rounding.

```
var_dump(25/7);           // float(3.5714285714286)    
var_dump((int) (25/7));   // int(3)   
var_dump(round(25/7));    // float(4)
```

[PhP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Answer (score 9):

use this....

```
intval(1700000 / 300000 )...
```

this returns the integer value.

Answer (score 7):

***FOR PHP 7 try `intdiv()` Function:***

> ***Syntax:*** `int intdiv($dividend, $divisor)`

```
          <?php           
           $dividend = 19; 
           $divisor = 3;  
           echo intdiv($dividend, $divisor); 
           ?>
```

***For Older versions of PHP:***

```
         <?php
     // Convert $total_minutes to hours and minutes.

         $total_minutes = 640;
         $minutes = $total_minutes % 60;
         $hours = ($total_minutes - $minutes) / 60;

         echo "Time taken was $hours hours $minutes minutes";
         ?>
```

Comment: As of August, 2019 this is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the shortform by adding |0 to the end

8/3|0

Comment: -1; this is a confusing abuse of the "bitwise or" operator. Admittedly, it *works* (since operands to bitwise operators get cast to integers, which rounds float values down, and the actual operation of bitwise or with 0 causes no change to the resulting integer value), but in order for a dev reading this code to understand *why* it works they need to know both the casting behaviour of PHP's bitwise operators (which is obscure trivia knowledge 99% of PHP devs won't have) and that a bitwise or with 0 leaves a value unchanged (not guaranteed, since not all web devs understand bit operations).

Comment: @MarkAmery, the fact that mos developers don't know about it doesn't mean that it doesn't work. And obviously that's a good reason to upvote, so people would learn how to use it.

Comment: yes it is confusing so should not be used in production code, but it does not change the fact that it is an interesting solution to the problem

Comment: @TomaszSwider some people might also search for the shortest solution (especially in some code challenges).

Comment: @Besi well yesterday I was one of these web devs who did not know how bit wise stuff works in PHP and after reading your solution I read about it and I am better programmer for it :)

Comment: This is used in JavaScript all the time. Programmers should be aware of this trick by now...

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to perform integer division in PHP.  The language doesn't have an operator for integer division, but there are several options for rounding the floating point quotient to an integer:

```
<?php
$pos = 1;
$neg = -1;
$divisor = 2;

// No rounding (float division)
var_dump($pos / $divisor);          //  0.5 (float)
var_dump($neg / $divisor);          // -0.5 (float)

// Round toward zero (like C integer division)
var_dump((int)($pos / $divisor));   //  0 (int)
var_dump((int)($neg / $divisor));   //  0 (int)

// Round half away from zero
var_dump(round($pos / $divisor));   //  1 (float)
var_dump(round($neg / $divisor));   // -1 (float)

// Round down
var_dump(floor($pos / $divisor));   //  0 (float)
var_dump(floor($neg / $divisor));   // -1 (float)

# And on PHP 7 you can round toward zero with intdiv():
var_dump(intdiv($pos, $divisor));   //  0 (int)
var_dump(intdiv($neg, $divisor));   //  0 (int)  Rounded toward zero
```

On PHP 7 you can use [`intdiv($p, $q)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) to directly perform integer division.  This is equivalent to `(int)($p / $q)` on PHP 5.

Answer (score 5):

```
(int)(1700000 / 300000);
```

use type casting.

Comment: Aw! Just because (0.1 + 0.7) == 0.799999... instead of 0.8 :) :) :)

Comment: @luc.chante the example you give happens due to floating point error. The exact value of `(0.1 + 0.7) * 10` is `7.99999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375`. It's perfectly correct that an `(int)` cast truncates this value to 7. When dividing an integer by another integer, as is the case in the question and answer here, such floating point error cannot change the post-truncation result.

Comment: This reproduce the exact behavior as expected in C/C++ when doing an integer division, so I don't see a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP version 7  => `intdiv(a,b)`

And for versions less than 7 (like 5.6) => `(int)floor(abs(a/b))`

Comment: Does not work for large integers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606140