# Integer (64-bit) division of large numbers without using intdiv() (before php7)

Tags: php

Tests are made at 64-bit system!

php7 has a nice function: `intdiv()`. The following code works perfect:

```
$number = 0x7fffffffffffffff;
$result = intdiv($number,62);
```

The result is `148764065110560900` (remainder 7) like expected.

But how do I this division in php<7 (e.g. php5.3)?

```
$number = 0x7fffffffffffffff;
$result = intval($number/62);
```

Here, the result is `148764065110560896`, smaller than the result of `intdiv(...)`. The reason is clear: `$number/62` is a floating point operation. So `$number` is converted to a float and looses precision (52 instead of 64 bits). So the result is rounded down.

Code to proof:

```
php -r '$a=0x7fffffffffffffff; $b=intdiv($a,62); $c=intval($a/62); printf("%d - %d = %d\n",$b,$c,$b-$c);'
// result: 148764065110560900 - 148764065110560896 = 4
```

My question:
Does anyone knows a function, that returns the correct integer value for e.g. `0x7fffffffffffffff/62` without using `intdiv()`?

## Solution based on answer by trincot

```
if (!function_exists('intdiv'))
{
    function intdiv($a,$b)
    {
        $a = intval($a);
        $b = intval($b);
        return ( $a - $a % $b ) / $b;
    }
}
```

I'll plan more tests to verify this replacement function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `%` operator to get the remainder. Then after subtraction of the remainder perform the division:

```
$rem = $number % 62;
$result = ($number - $rem) / 62;
```

Comment: Good idea! At the beginning I thought, rounding of the difference takes place. Then I read [PHP /](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and found: "The division operator ("/") returns a float value unless the two operands are integers (or strings that get converted to integers) and the numbers are evenly divisible, in which case an integer value will be returned.". It seems to work at php7 and php5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding that, if in case you need more precision, you can consider Arbitrary Precision Mathematics, BCMath:

```
$res=bcdiv($number , "62", 255);
```

148764065110560900.112903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451