# Converting number from float to Int returns unexpected answer.

Tags: php, int

Unexpected result in php when carrying out simple math to convert from a unit in meters to mm.

```
$width  = (float)1.0050;
echo 'Width: '.$width.'m';
$width = (int)($width*1000);
echo 'Width:'. $width . 'mm';
```

This is returning

> Width: 1.005m 
> Width:1004mm

When expected result would be 1005mm.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP typecasting float->int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055469/php-typecasting-float-int)

Comment: You may read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

internally php represent $width as float with value: 1.0049999999999999
the casting operation simply strip the number after the coma, the you receive 1004.

Use round instead:

```
round($width * 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked this issue!

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, (float)anyNumberWithDecimals does not convert METRIC units, in any program language. It makes a cast, to specify what type of variable is.